# Why does Rails try to guess the filename when I `include` a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have the following setup where one of my classes includes a module that's located in another file

The key thing to note is that the module `MyBar` does *not* live in a file with a similar name. It lives in `my_foo.rb` instead.

#### my_foo.rb

```
module MyBar
  def self.test
    "This is a test string"
  end
end
```

#### some_class.rb

```
require 'my_foo'

class SomeClass
  include MyBar

  def initialize
    puts MyBar.test
  end
end
```

When I run this I get a `NameError`

```
NameError - uninitialized constant MyBar
```

It looks like Rails is trying to be smart and assume that because the module name is `MyBar` it should be located in a file similarly named `my_bar.rb`.

I tried testing this theory by changing the name to what it expects, and it suddenly worked correctly

```
my_foo.rb (renamed)-> my_bar.rb
```

The question is

1. Why does Rails do this? Seems like it's assuming too much. I get that it's "convention over configuration", but there are several valid reasons to have the filename not match the module name.
2. How do I override this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has something to do with how the **autoloading** works in Rails.

Rails only auto loads when you try to use a new class/module name that matches the file name and located under the `/lib/` directory.

**To fix your issue**, you can put your `my_foo.rb` file under `/lib/` directory and require it like this: `require 'lib/my_foo'`

See the Rails Documentation for [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) for more information about how auto loading works in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

The `app` directory is not included in `$LOAD_PATH` in rails for various reasons (mainly autoloading and class reload while you edit stuff).

If you want to use constants that don't match the file name, you want to locate them in `lib` directory and require them (`lib` is included in `$LOAD_PATH`).

If you really want to include a file in the `app` directory, you probably want to try with a `require Rails.root.join('app', 'models', 'my_foo.rb').to_s`. I'm not sure what will break though, you are really going against rails convention.